# Why is my count in polygon number greater than the number of raw data points?

Tags: shapefile, gps, overlapping-features, count

I'm working with GPS points and want to count how many of them fall within protected areas of 4 countries in Southern Africa (Eswatini, Zimbabwe, Mozambique and South Africa). I get the shape files for each from here https://www.protectedplanet.net/

The issue is there are 1768 GPS data points but I get a count of 1990 points within the protected areas which should be impossible.

I thought it would work out if I did it separately but no luck. The number of overlapping points are 59 from Eswatini, 819 from Mozambique,154 from Zimbabwe and 958 from South Africa which still sums to 1990.

Then I thought maybe some of the protected areas overlap across countries so some points are counted twice but it doesn't look like that's the case either.

I've carried it out in QGIS using Count points in polygon and in R with st_intersects and get the same result.

Here are the GPS data if you'd like to replicate what I've done https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IXTCQXAmQQehxpTmJn9aB4gfp1Bm2RH2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The overlap may be within a given country (two or more polygons / polygon parts of the same country overlap each others). Beware of multiparts

Comment: ah ok, I didn't think of that. How can I blend the multiparts into one?

Comment: By the way, is it possible that some points are out of (any of) the protected areas? If you are sure that each point somehow lies within some protected area then you probably need to use the shapefile of countries (say from Natural Earth data) not the protected areas.

Comment: They definitely don't all fall within protected areas so I can't do the Natural Earth option unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

Main problem is overlapping (self-intersection) but, there also are a few multiparts. Following image presents a critical area in Zimbabwe shapefile. You can also observe that there are 182 features in attributes table.

[image]

By using 'Multipart to singlepart' method from Processing Tool Box, you can get following result:

[image]

Attributes table confirms multipart presence with 184 features.

For eliminating overlapping (but this will create much more features) it can be used 'Polygon-self intersection' tool of Processing Tool Box. Result is observed as follows:

[image]

In attributes table it can be observed 301 features (117 features more than single parts layer). This is the reason of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @xunilk, there is probably a problem with your shapefile. Fixing it is a good way to remove your errors. Another quick way is to change the source of your shape file. From [Natural Earth Data](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads), using shapefile `ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp` give the results as expected.

[image]

Comment: He needs a shapefile of protected areas; not of administrative areas of countries.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't fully comprehend it then. But still, the main idea is to change the source of shapefile if possible.